# PHP foreach multiple results

Tags: php, foreach

I´m not an advanced php coder so I need some help here.

I´m trying to echo list items with a link pointing to the full image and the thumnail.

This is the desired result:

```
<li>
    <a href="fullimagepath1">
        <img src="thumnailpath1" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="fullimagepath2">
        <img src="thumnailpath2" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="fullimagepath3">
        <img src="thumnailpath3" />
    </a>
</li>
...
```

This is the code I'm using

```
    <?php
        $images = rwmb_meta( 'product_gallery', 'type=image&size=press-thumb' );
    $fullimages = rwmb_meta( 'product_gallery', 'type=image&size=productfull-thumb' );
            foreach ( $fullimages as $fimages)
            foreach ( $images as $image)
                {
                    echo "<li><a class='thumb' href='{$fimages['url']}'><img src='{$image['url']}' /></a></li>";

    } ?>
```

The problem is that I'm getting the thumbnails but multiplied by the number of real results. If I have 3 thumbnails for my gallery the result will be 9 thumbnails, if I have 5 will get 25.

How can I fix the code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what $images and $fullimages contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this line `foreach ( $fullimages as $fimages)` which is triggering inner loops.

Since you probably have 3 images and both array hold three items array, loop will run 3 times inside a bigger loop which will also execute 3 times. So you have 9 items.

On your code

```
foreach ( $fullimages as $fimages) //Because of this loop next statement executes
foreach ( $images as $image) {
  echo "<li><a class='thumb' href='{$fimages['url']}'><img src='{$image['url']}' /></a></li>";
}
```

What you probably want is?

```
foreach ( $fullimages as $k => $fimages) {
                      // ^ Get the index of the array
  echo "<li><a class='thumb' href='{$fimages['url']}'>
       <img src='{$images[$k]['url']}' /></a></li>";
                       // ^ Use that key to find the thumbnail from $images array
}
```

Comment: Thanks Starx! It's working! I will try to learn how this works in deep.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
foreach ( $fullimages as $fimages)
{
    foreach ( $images as $image)
                echo "<li><a class='thumb' href='{$fimages['url']}'><img src='{$image['url']}' /></a></li>";

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and iterate over

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($images);$i++){
    echo $images[$i]['url'], $fullimages[$i]['url'];
}
```

Or use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

```
array_map(function($image, $fullimage){
    echo $image['url'], $fullimage['url'];
}, $images, $fullimages);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing images like this:

```
$images = array(
 'fullpath' => '...'
 'thumbpath' => '...'    
)
```

instead of two separate arrays. and just loop over one array.

or use iterator functions like `next($array)`, `current($array)` to simultaneously iterate over two arrays.